Movie where a guy shoots everyone in the room with one bullet by making it curve
I can only remember two parts and I feel they are quite iconic as when I tried to describe this to a friend he remembers as well. 
The main character works in an office and I remember at the end there is an X on the ground in the office where he works and the antagonist is on the phone talking to the protagonist about something and he says something along the lines of "well fuck" and gets shot by a sniper.
The first being when he has to reach into a loom and grab something (I cant quite remember).
Second being near the end I believe where he curves the bullet and kills everyone in the room with all the people willing and knowing what was going on.
Maybe I'm mixing up movies but I think that's all one movie

Howcome it is duplicate. Although it is about same movie but other question doesnot mentions the bullet is taking curve path.

I believe you are looking for Movie Wanted
I do remember this movie for curved bullets, there is this scene,

Wesley is left penniless once again. A man is seen at Wesley's desk much later. Sloan appears and points a gun at the back of the man's head. The man turns around and is revealed to be a decoy. Sloan is killed by Wesley using a long-distance bullet. Wesley states his accomplishments saying "this is me taking control, from Sloan, from the Fraternity, from Janice, from billing reports, from ergonomic keyboards, from cheating girlfriends, and sack-of-shit best friends, this is me taking back control of my life", and asks the audience: "What the fuck have you done lately?"

This is scene where everyone standing in a circle got killed .

The members are considering breaking the code and killing Wesley, but Fox, who believes more in the code, turns on her fellow assassins and curves a bullet that kills everyone but Sloan and Wesley.

This movie was very famous in India as Angelina Jolie's action movie with curved bullets. 
